# how to connect Ajax to an external php file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I am new to Ajax and I wrote the following code in php and javascript. I wrote the call in Ajax but feel that there is something wrong. Everything is working except the call to the `insert.php` file.

```
    <div class="container">
    <form action="" method="post" id="add_days_form">
         <div class="table-responsive">
            <span id="error"></span>
               <table class="table table-bordered" id="add_all">
                  <tr>
                         <th>Enter Day</th>
                         <th>Enter Time</th>
                         <th>Enter Stage</th>
                         <th>Enter Class Name</th>
                         <th><button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add"><i class="fas fa-plus"></i></button> </th>

                     </tr> 
               </table>
               <br/>
               <div align="center">
                   <input type="submit" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert">
               </div>
        </div>
     </form>
</div>
<script>    
        $(document).ready(function(){
        $(document).on('click','.add',function(){
        var html='';
        html +='<tr>';
        html += '<td><input type="date" name="slot_date[]" class="form-control day"/></td>';
        html +='<td><select name="slot_time[]" class="form-control slot"><option value="">Select Slot</option><?php echo fill_slots(); ?></select></td>';
        html +='<td><select name="slot_stage[]" class="form-control stage"><option value="">Select Stage</option><?php echo fill_stages(); ?></select></td>';
        html +='<td><select name="slot_class[]" class="form-control class"><option value="">Select Class Name</option><?php echo fill_classes(); ?></select></td>';
        html +='<td><button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove"><i class="fas fa-minus"></i></button></td></tr>';
        $('#add_all').append(html);
                         });

        $(document).on('click','.remove',function(){
                $(this).closest('tr').remove(); 
            });

        $('#add_days_form').on('submit', function(event){
                event.preventDefault();
                var error = '' ;
                $('.day').each(function(){
                    var count =1;
                    if ($(this).val()=='')
                        {
                            error+="<p>Enter Date at Row Number " +count+ "</p>";
                            return false;
                        }
                    count = count + 1;

                });
                $('.slot').each(function(){
                    var count=1;
                    if($(this).val()==''){

                        error+="<p>Enter Time at Row Number " +count+ "</p>";
                        return false;
                    }
                    count = count + 1;
                });
                $('.stage').each(function(){
                    var count=1;
                    if($(this).val()==''){

                        error+="<p>Enter Stage at Row Number " +count+ "</p>";
                        return false;
                    }
                    count = count + 1;
                });
                $('.class').each(function(){
                    var count=1;
                    if($(this).val()==''){

                        error+="<p>Enter Class at Row Number " +count+ "</p>";
                        return false;
                    }
                    count = count +1;
                });

                var form_data = $(this).serialize();
                if(error == ''){
                    $.ajax({
                        url:"insert.php",
                        method:"POST",
                        data:form_data,
                        success:function(data)
                        {
                            if(data == 'ok')
                                {
                                    $('#add_all').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                                    $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Day Saved</div>');}
                        }
                    });

                }
                else{
                    $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' +error+ '</div>');
                }
            });

        });

        </script>
```

Here is my `insert.php` file that includes the script I want to run and send back to Ajax:

```
        <?php
        include "../includes/db.php";
        if(isset($_POST['slot_date']))
        {
            $slot_date = $_POST['slot_date'];
            $slot_date_name = date('l', strtotime($slot_date));
            $slot_time = $_POST['slot_time'];
            $slot_stage = $_POST['slot_stage'];
            $slot_class = $_POST['slot_class'];

            for($count = 0; $count < count($slot_date); $count++)

            {
                $query="INSERT INTO day_slot_stage_class(day_date,day_name,slot_id,stage_id,swim_class_id) VALUES ('{$slot_date}', {$slot_date_name}', {$slot_time}' , {$slot_stage} ,'{$slot_class}')";

                $run_query=mysqli_query($connection,$query);
                confirmQuery($run_query);

            }

            }
           $result = mysqli_fetch_all($run_query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);

            if(isset($result)){
                echo 'ok';          
        }
        ?>
```

Could you please help me figure out what is wrong?

Comment: Have you watched the request / response in the browser's developer tools? Opened the browser's console? You'll see the errors there.

Comment: thank you, I opened it now and found these errors VM630:1047 WebSocket connection to 'ws://localhost:8125/' failed: Error in connection establishment: net::ERR_CONNECTION_REFUSED
createWebSocket @ VM630:1047
jquery.min.js:2 POST http://localhost:8888/admin/insert.php 404 (Not Found)
send @ jquery.min.js:2
ajax @ jquery.min.js:2
(anonymous) @ option.php?source=setup:361
dispatch @ jquery.min.js:2
y.handle @ jquery.min.js:2

Comment: `insert.php` needs to be in the same directory as the HTML page that's sending the AJAX request. Or you should use an absolute path to `insert.php`.

Comment: the insert.php is in the same directory. I can't figure out the problem. I feel the problem starts from the Ajax part or the php code but have been in that over 6 hours with no success

Comment: Are you sure it's not hitting the insert.php file at all? A quick way to test would be to add error_log('works'); at the top of the php file...you know it reaches it at least :P by having the error log open when testing ;)

Answer (score 0):

**Problems:**

**In insert.php:**

```
Error 2 - strtotime() expects parameter 1 to be string, array given in file path-to/insert.php on line 7
Error 8 - Array to string conversion in file path-to/insert.php on line 14
Error 2 - mysqli_fetch_all() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given in file path-to/insert.php on line 33
```

So, the values in the `$query` sql statement are wrong. There are also some apostrophs missing:

```
INSERT INTO day_slot_stage_class (day_date, day_name, slot_id, stage_id, swim_class_id) VALUES (
    'Array', 
    Thursday', 
    Array' , 
    Array ,
    'Array'
)
```

The `$slot_date_name` should be inside the `for` loop.

The statement `$result = mysqli_fetch_all($run_query,MYSQLI_ASSOC);` has nothing to do in there at all.

An error handling/reporting system is needed as well, in order to be able to catch/track eventual errors. Read *"Diverse"*.

**In index.php:**

You have no `error` callback for your ajax request. This also is a reason, why you didn't see any errors on screen. See *"My code"*.

In short, maintaining your coding style, your code in `insert.php` should look just like this:

```
<?php

include "../includes/error_handlers.php";
include "../includes/db.php";

$slot_date = $_POST['slot_date'] ?? [];
$slot_time = $_POST['slot_time'] ?? [];
$slot_stage = $_POST['slot_stage'] ?? [];
$slot_class = $_POST['slot_class'] ?? [];

for ($count = 0; $count < count($slot_date); $count++) {
    $slot_date_name = date('l', strtotime($slot_date[$count]));

    $query = "INSERT INTO day_slot_stage_class (
                    day_date,
                    day_name,
                    slot_id,
                    stage_id,
                    swim_class_id
                ) VALUES (
                    '{$slot_date[$count]}',
                    '{$slot_date_name}',
                    '{$slot_time[$count]}',
                    '{$slot_stage[$count]}',
                    '{$slot_class[$count]}'
                )";

    mysqli_query($connection, $query);
}

echo 'ok';
```

See, no checking if the operation was successful is made, because in that included file `error_handlers.php` are two error handling functions defined, which catch each error/warning/notice/etc.

---

**Diverse:**

- You need an "error" callback for the ajax request along with the "success" one.
- You need both client-side and server-side validations. I would suggest to use a validation plugin. [This](https://jqueryvalidation.org/) is a powerful one. It was my favorite.
- Use prepared statements in order to avoid [sql injection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/SQL_injection). So read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli#prepare).
- You should use the object oriented mysqli instead of the procedural one. For example: `$connection->prepare($sql)` instead of `mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql)`.
- You should familiarize yourself with error handling/reporting. So read [this](https://phpdelusions.net/articles/error_reporting) and [this](https://phpdelusions.net/mysqli/error_reporting).
- Important: Since you just execute an ajax request, define the button named "submit" as a `type="button"` one: `<input type="button" name="submit"...>`. Use `type="submit"` buttons only when you want to submit a form in the standard way, e.g. using the `action` attribute of the `form` tag.
- Try to avoid using php code in javascript, like in your `$(document).on('click', '.add', function () {...}`, where you call the functions `fill_slots`, `fill_stages` and `fill_classes`.
- I would suggest to use the [DataTables](https://www.datatables.net/) library for tables. A great library. And it works perfectly in conjunction with [Bootstrap](https://www.datatables.net/examples/styling/bootstrap4.html). See [this library](https://www.gyrocode.com/projects/jquery-datatables-checkboxes/) too.
- The icons should be like: `<i class="fa ..."></i>`, not like `<i class="fas ...">`. Search overall and correct.
- Inside your `$(selector).each()` functions, use the `index` parameter instead of a count variable. See [$(selector).each()](https://api.jquery.com/each/).
- In JS, use strict equalities (`===`) instead of loose ones (`==`).

---

**My code:**

Don't forget to change the db credentials in `includes/db.php` with yours.

And, again, very important: read the docs I gave you regarding error handling/reporting, then try to implement it. It's about to :

- Just define two functions - `set_error_handler` and `set_exception_handler` - in a file. Then to include the file in the other project pages.
- To enable the internal report functions - as I did in `includes/db.php` below.

If you do it right, then you'll not need to check for errors "by hand" anymore, since those functions will take care of everything for you.

**index.php**

```
<?php

function fill_slots() {
    $options = '';
    $options .= '<option value="1">Slot 1</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="2">Slot 2</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="3">Slot 3</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="4">Slot 4</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="5">Slot 5</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="6">Slot 6</option>';

    return $options;
}

function fill_stages() {
    $options = '';
    $options .= '<option value="1">Stage 1</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="2">Stage 2</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="3">Stage 3</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="4">Stage 4</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="5">Stage 5</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="6">Stage 6</option>';

    return $options;
}

function fill_classes() {
    $options = '';
    $options .= '<option value="1">Class 1</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="2">Class 2</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="3">Class 3</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="4">Class 4</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="5">Class 5</option>';
    $options .= '<option value="6">Class 6</option>';

    return $options;
}
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1" />
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, user-scalable=yes" />
        <meta charset="UTF-8" />
        <!-- The above 3 meta tags must come first in the head -->

        <title>Demo</title>

        <!-- CSS assets -->
        <link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet" />
        <link href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/css/bootstrap.min.css" type="text/css" rel="stylesheet">

        <!-- JS assets -->
        <script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
        <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.14.3/umd/popper.min.js"></script>
        <script src="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

        <script type="text/javascript">
            $(document).ready(function () {
                $(document).on('click', '.add', function () {
                    var rowTemplate = $('#rowTemplateContainer tbody').html();
                    $('#add_all tbody').append(rowTemplate);
                });

                $('#add_all').on('click', '.remove', function () {
                    $(this).closest('tr').remove();
                });

                $('#saveButton').on('click', function (event) {
                    var errors = [];

                    $('#add_all .day').each(function (index) {
                        if ($(this).val() === '') {
                            errors.push('Enter Date at Row Number ' + (index + 1));
                        }
                    });

                    $('#add_all .slot').each(function (index) {
                        if ($(this).val() === '') {
                            errors.push('Enter Time at Row Number ' + (index + 1));
                        }
                    });

                    $('#add_all .stage').each(function (index) {
                        if ($(this).val() === '') {
                            errors.push('Enter Stage at Row Number ' + (index + 1));
                        }
                    });

                    $('#add_all .class').each(function (index) {
                        if ($(this).val() === '') {
                            errors.push('Enter Class at Row Number ' + (index + 1));
                        }
                    });

                    if (errors.length > 0) {
                        $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + errors.join('<br/>') + '</div>');
                        return false;
                    }

                    $.ajax({
                        method: 'post',
                        dataType: 'html',
                        url: 'insert.php',
                        data: $('#add_days_form').serialize(),
                        success: function (response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
                            $('#add_all').find("tr:gt(0)").remove();
                            $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-success">Day Saved</div>');
                        },
                        error: function (jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
                            /*
                             * When a HTTP error occurs, errorThrown receives the "reason phrase" of the
                             * HTTP response message - such as "Not Found", or "Internal Server Error".
                             */
                            var message = errorThrown;

                            /*
                             * If the body of the HTTP response message exists, then it
                             * is saved in the responseText property of the jqXHR object.
                             */
                            if (jqXHR.responseText !== null && jqXHR.responseText !== 'undefined' && jqXHR.responseText !== '') {
                                message = jqXHR.responseText;
                            }

                            $('#error').html('<div class="alert alert-danger">' + message + '</div>');
                        }
                    });
                });
            });
        </script>
    </head>
    <body>

        <div class="container">
            <form action="" method="post" id="add_days_form">
                <span id="error"></span>

                <div class="table-responsive">
                    <table id="add_all" class="table table-bordered">
                        <thead>
                            <tr>
                                <th>Enter Day</th>
                                <th>Enter Time</th>
                                <th>Enter Stage</th>
                                <th>Enter Class Name</th>
                                <th>
                                    <button type="button" name="add" class="btn btn-success btn-sm add">
                                        <i class="fa fa-plus"></i>
                                    </button>
                                </th>
                            </tr>
                        </thead>
                        <tbody></tbody>
                    </table>

                    <br/>

                    <div align="center">
                        <input type="button" id="saveButton" name="submit" class="btn btn-info" value="Insert">
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>

        <table id="rowTemplateContainer" style="display: none;">
            <tbody>
                <tr>
                    <td>
                        <input type="date" name="slot_date[]" class="form-control day"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="slot_time[]" class="form-control slot">
                            <option value="">Select Slot</option>
                            <?php echo fill_slots(); ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="slot_stage[]" class="form-control stage">
                            <option value="">Select Stage</option>
                            <?php echo fill_stages(); ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <select name="slot_class[]" class="form-control class">
                            <option value="">Select Class Name</option>
                            <?php echo fill_classes(); ?>
                        </select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <button type="button" name="remove" class="btn btn-danger btn-sm remove">
                            <i class="fa fa-minus"></i>
                        </button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>

    </body>
</html>
```

**insert.php**

```
<?php

require '../includes/db.php';
require_once '../includes/InvalidInputValue.php';

use App\InvalidInputValue;

/*
 * ======================
 * Read the posted values
 * ======================
 */
$slotDate = $_POST['slot_date'] ?? [];
$slotTime = $_POST['slot_time'] ?? [];
$slotStage = $_POST['slot_stage'] ?? [];
$slotClass = $_POST['slot_class'] ?? [];

// Number of rows.
$numberOfRows = count($slotDate);

// The names of the days.
$slotDateName = [];

// Eventual errors.
$errors = [];

/*
 * =====================================================
 * Validate the values. If invalid values were provided,
 * activate the "error" callback of the ajax request.
 * =====================================================
 */
try {
    // Check if any data provided.
    if ($numberOfRows === 0) {
        throw new InvalidInputValue('You did\'t provide any data');
    }

    for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfRows; $i++) {
        // Validate the date.
        if (empty($slotDate[$i])) {
            $errors[] = 'Enter Date at Row Number ' . ($i + 1);
        } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */ else {
            // Add the current name of the day to the list.
            $slotDateName[$i] = date('l', strtotime($slotDate[$i]));
        }

        // Validate the time.
        if (empty($slotTime[$i])) {
            $errors[] = 'Enter Time at Row Number ' . ($i + 1);
        } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

        // Validate the stage.
        if (empty($slotStage[$i])) {
            $errors[] = 'Enter Stage at Row Number ' . ($i + 1);
        } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */

        // Validate the class.
        if (empty($slotClass[$i])) {
            $errors[] = 'Enter Class at Row Number ' . ($i + 1);
        } /* Other validations here using elseif statements */
    }

    if ($errors) {
        throw new InvalidInputValue(implode('<br/>', $errors));
    }
} catch (InvalidInputValue $exc) {
    /*
     * Throw an error to be catched by the "error" callback of the ajax request.
     * This can be achieved by sending a specific or a custom response header to the client.
     *
     *  - Specific header: A header containing any already assigned status code.
     *  - Custom header: A header containing any NOT already assigned status code. This type of
     *    headers have the reason phrase "Unassigned" in the official HTTP Status Code Registry.
     *
     * @link https://www.iana.org/assignments/http-status-codes/http-status-codes.xhtml HTTP Status Code Registry.
     */
    header('HTTP/1.1 500 Internal Server Error', TRUE, 500);
    echo $exc->getMessage();
    exit();
}

/*
 * ===================================
 * Insert the values into the db table
 * ===================================
 */

/*
 * -----------------------------------------------------------
 * Step 1: Prepare the sql statement for execution - ONLY ONCE
 * -----------------------------------------------------------
 */

/*
 * The SQL statement to be prepared. Notice the so-called markers,
 * e.g. the "?" signs. They will be replaced later with the
 * corresponding values when using mysqli_stmt::bind_param.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$sql = 'INSERT INTO day_slot_stage_class (
            day_date,
            day_name,
            slot_id,
            stage_id,
            swim_class_id
        ) VALUES (
            ?, ?, ?, ?, ?
        )';

/*
 * Prepare the SQL statement for execution - ONLY ONCE.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.prepare.php
 */
$statement = mysqli_prepare($connection, $sql);

/*
 * -----------------------------------------
 * Step 2: Save the values into the db table
 * -----------------------------------------
 */
for ($i = 0; $i < $numberOfRows; $i++) {
    /*
     * Bind variables for the parameter markers (?) in the
     * SQL statement that was passed to prepare(). The first
     * argument of bind_param() is a string that contains one
     * or more characters which specify the types for the
     * corresponding bind variables.
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php
     */
    mysqli_stmt_bind_param($statement, 'ssiii'
            , $slotDate[$i]
            , $slotDateName[$i]
            , $slotTime[$i]
            , $slotStage[$i]
            , $slotClass[$i]
    );

    /*
     * Execute the prepared SQL statement.
     * When executed any parameter markers which exist will
     * automatically be replaced with the appropriate data.
     *
     * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.execute.php
     */
    mysqli_stmt_execute($statement);
}

/*
 * ---------------------------------
 * Step 3: Close the used components
 * ---------------------------------
 */

/*
 * Close the prepared statement. It also deallocates the statement handle.
 * If the statement has pending or unread results, it cancels them
 * so that the next query can be executed.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.close.php
 */
mysqli_stmt_close($statement);

/*
 * Close the previously opened database connection.
 * Not really needed because the PHP engine closes
 * the connection anyway when the PHP script is finished.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.close.php
 */
mysqli_close($connection);
```

**includes/db.php**

```
<?php

/*
 * This page contains the code for creating a mysqli connection instance.
 */

// Db configs.
define('HOST', 'localhost');
define('PORT', 3306);
define('DATABASE', 'tests');
define('USERNAME', 'root');
define('PASSWORD', 'root');

/*
 * Enable internal report functions. This enables the exception handling,
 * e.g. mysqli will not throw PHP warnings anymore, but mysqli exceptions
 * (mysqli_sql_exception).
 *
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR: Report errors from mysqli function calls.
 * MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT: Throw a mysqli_sql_exception for errors instead of warnings.
 *
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/class.mysqli-driver.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-driver.report-mode.php
 * @link http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.constants.php
 */
$mysqliDriver = new mysqli_driver();
$mysqliDriver->report_mode = (MYSQLI_REPORT_ERROR | MYSQLI_REPORT_STRICT);

/*
 * Create a new db connection.
 *
 * @see http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.construct.php
 */
$connection = mysqli_connect(HOST, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DATABASE, PORT);
```

**includes/InvalidInputValue.php**

```
<?php

namespace App;

/**
 * Custom exception. Thrown when posted user input values are invalid.
 */
class InvalidInputValue extends \Exception {

}
```

**Table definition**

```
CREATE TABLE `day_slot_stage_class` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `day_date` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `day_name` varchar(100) DEFAULT NULL,
  `slot_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `stage_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `swim_class_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Comment: Many Many thanks, you saved me a lot of time searching and googling, Iam still new to php and Ajax trying to learn through tutorials and enrolled in a lot of online courses. all your advices are really valuable and I will read them all. again many thanks